# Save output from Shiny to file

Tags: r, file, shiny

I am creating function that launches shiny app.

This will allow user to make multiple selections.

From what I understand, shiny doesn't return data to the calling program (please clarify this)

Hence, I am saving to a text file, which will eventually be read by the program, then delete the text file.

Problem started when I added `file.append(colorfile,output$col)` within shiny

When I launch shiny app, I get error, (end of question is the code, and here is the [entire R script](https://github.com/ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab/blob/master/R/RanglaPunjab.R))

```
> CherryPickPalette("BiryaniRice","Kulfi","Haveli2")

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7208
Warning: Error in $.shinyoutput: Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed.
  54: stop
  53: $.shinyoutput
  50: server [c:\RanglaPunjab/R/RanglaPunjab.R#230]
Error in `$.shinyoutput`(output, col) : 
  Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed.
```

Function CherryPicker Palette

```
CherryPickPalette <- function (name, name2=NULL, name3=NULL){

  if ((nargs() < 2) || (nargs() > 3)){
    stop("Enter 2 or 3 valid palettes. Run ListPalette() for list of palettes.")
  }
  if (nargs() == 2){
    new_pal <- MergePalette(name,name2)
  }
  else if (nargs() == 3){
    new_pal <- MergePalette(name,name2,name3)
  }

  if (interactive()){
    colorfile <- paste(getwd(),"colorfile.txt",sep="/")
    if (!file.exists(colorfile)){
      file.create(colorfile)
    }
    shinyApp(
      ui = fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Cherry Pick Your Own Palette!"),
        sidebarPanel (hr(),
                      selectInput('col', 'Options', new_pal, multiple=TRUE, selectize=FALSE, size = 15)
                      ),
        mainPanel(
          h5('Your custom colors',style = "font-weight: bold;"),
          fluidRow(column(12,verbatimTextOutput("col"))))
      ),
      server = function(input,output,session){
        output$col <- renderPrint(input$col)
        file.append(colorfile,output$col)
      }

    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file.append function will append one file to the other. (not add text to a file), take a look at cat or sink functions

The following seems to work for me

```
  server = function(input,output,session){
   outuputdata<-  reactive({
      input$col
    })

    output$col <- { 
      renderPrint(outuputdata())
    }
    observe({
      message <- paste(outuputdata(),"\n")
      cat(message,file=colorfile, append=TRUE)
      })
   }
```

Comment: I had additional question, and created new post. Please answer if possible, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726976/save-output-to-file-after-r-shiny-terminates